# Is there a way to paginate on github repo api?

Tags: github, github-api

Is there a way to query only 20 user repositories at a time ?
Or a configurable number like pagesize.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories

Just does not say anything about getting a specific number of repositories with each call.

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination

Comment: Oh, thanks. Should have just searched on that page. Sorry.